# How to customize the order of groups in Open API definitions

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a Jhipster generated reactive spring-boot application. By default jhipster generates 2 different groups in open api definitions: `default` and `management`. In the UI, `default` is the first option and management is the second one. I have added a new group using below code:

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi petOpenApi() {
   String paths[] = {"/pet/**"};
   return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("custom").pathsToMatch(paths)
         .build();
}
```

Here in my swagger UI I need to make this group as the selected one when the page is loaded. As of now `default` is the selected option